# Extract portion of an xml without using tostring in python

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, elementtree, c14n

Say I have an XML code like this one:

```
<a>
 <na:Data xmlns:na="http://some_site.com#" Ref="http://another_site.com" 
  Key="value">
  <b>
  <c>some_c_attrib</c>
  <d>some_d_attrib</d>
  <e>some_e_attrib</e>
   <f>some_f_attrib</f>
   <g>some_g_attrib</g>
  </b>
  <h>
   <i>some_i_attrib</i>
   <j>some_j_attrib</j>
  </h>
 </na:Data>
 <da:Newtag xmlns:da="http://new_site.com">
  <k name="http://new_new_site.com"/>
```

And there are few more lines after this. I have parsed the xml using `ET.parse(FILENAME)` and then wrote it in a new file using `write_c14n("new.xml")`. I now want to extract portion of this new.xml into another xml file where I just want the portion starting from `<na:Data xmlns:na="http://some_site.com#" Ref="http://another_site.com" Key="value">` and ending at `</h>`.

However, I do not want to use `tostring()` as it doesn't retain the canonicalization of the xml as obtained by using `write_c14n()`. I was wondering if copying just that portion from new.xml and writing it into another xml will help but I guess it is adding some extra new lines in between and also not retaining the format of the xml as it is.

I have tried out the following ways:

In this way I tried creating another xml with new root as `<na:Data xmlns:na="http://some_site.com#" Ref="http://another_site.com" Key="value">`:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = etree.parse('file_location/file_to_read.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

sub_root = etree.Element('{http://some_site.com#}Data')
for node in root.find('.//na:Data', namespaces = {'na':'http://some_site.com#'}).getchildren():


    sub_root.append(node.element)

new_tree = etree.ElementTree(sub_root)
```

I just need the object of the new_tree so I can use it as new_tree. However, if I print the above new_tree using `tostring()` [i.e print `etree.tostring(root_tree,pretty_print=True)`] this is the output I get:

```
<ns0:Data xmlns:ns0="http://some_site.com#"><b>
 <c>some_c_attrib</c>
 <d>some_d_attrib</d>
 <e>some_e_attrib</e>
  <f>some_f_attrib</f>
  <g>some_g_attrib</g>
 </b>
 <h>
  <i>some_i_attrib</i>
  <j>some_j_attrib</j>
 </h>
</ns0:Data>
```

As you can see the `na:Data` got replaced by `ns0:Data` and also its keys and values (`Ref="http://another_site.com" Key="value"`) are missing. I need a way which can extract a portion of xml as it is with all the attributes,keys and values.

Comment: I assume that something is missing here: "...starting from and ending at .". Please edit your question.

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek: I edited the xml, </na:Data> was missing in the xml. So basically I want this entire portion of the xml as it is :
 <na:Data xmlns:na="http://some_site.com#" Ref="http://another_site.com" 
  Key="value">
  <b>
  <c>some_c_attrib</c>
  <d>some_d_attrib</d>
  <e>some_e_attrib</e>
   <f>some_f_attrib</f>
   <g>some_g_attrib</g>
  </b>
  <h>
   <i>some_i_attrib</i>
   <j>some_j_attrib</j>
  </h>
 </na:Data>

Comment: I was mostly interested to extract the portion of the xml in my previous reply so restricted my xml to show just that portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create new elements. Just parse the original XML file, extract the `na:Data` child element, and write it to a new file.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('file_location/file_to_read.xml')
Data = tree.find('.//na:Data', namespaces={'na':'http://some_site.com#'})
etree.ElementTree(Data).write_c14n("new.xml")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mzjn. This worked. Just wondering how etree.ElementTree(Data) is able to pull all the children and grand-children of the element. Could you explain a bit. Sorry am very new to lxml.

Comment: XML is a way to represent data in a hierarchical way. `Data` is a reference to an element object (a hierarchical data structure). If the element has descendants, they are part of that structure. Does this help?

Comment: Yeah it surely does. So if I want to extract this portion:
<h>
   <i>some_i_attrib</i>
   <j>some_j_attrib</j>
</h>

using :

Data = tree.find('.//h')
etree.ElementTree(Data).write_c14n("new.xml")

The new.xml file looks like this:

<h xmlns:na="http://some_site.com#">
   <i>some_i_attrib</i>
   <j>some_j_attrib</j>
  </h>

Is there any way to not include the namespace to the 'h' tag ? I want the output to be : 

<h>
   <i>some_i_attrib</i>
   <j>some_j_attrib</j>
</h>

Thank you once again.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is a way. But please post a new question if you need help with that. Code and XML markup is hard to read in comments.

Comment: Sure @mzjn, however using objectify I could get rid of the namespace in the element:
objectify.deannotate(root, cleanup_namespaces=True)
Thanks.